# How to deploy a laravel-websockets server on Heroku free plan?

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, websocket

I just implemented web-sockets on my laravel php app using the laravel-websockets library. I wanted to know how to deploy it to heroku as it requires me to run another server with command "php artisan websockets:serve". 
I have already deployed the app on heroku, I just need help with deploying the websocket server to Heroku.

Comment: What have you tried? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I have not tried anything. I don't know how to create another server that will act as a websocket server.There are heroku docs..but none related to PHP or laravel.

Answer (score 2):

> It's not currently possible to have a websockets server running
>   alongside a PHP app on Heroku.

As stated in https://help.heroku.com/8R7OO0ZV/can-i-run-a-websockets-server-using-php-on-heroku which was the first result of a search of `"heroku websocket php"` on google.

Comment: I was searching for laravel heroku websockets and so didn't get any answers.